# Retrieve data from database to front-end

Tags: extensions, jdatabase

I created a form using ConvertForm extension for guests to submit information (name, age, ...etc) into my Joomla database.
Is there a way to display the information the guests submitted to another page on the website? (retrieving data from the database and putting it in an article or something on front-end)
Can this be done through an extension or should I learn PHP to be able to do it?

Comment: It may be a little bit hard for you to get it done. You have to create a module in order to display such information on a specifc page. I can help you with it. What's the table name and  the fields you want to display?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way (*or two*):

- If you want to use an extensión, you can try with  [**DB Embed Pro**](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/core-enhancements/data-reports/db-embed-pro/) 
  This allows you to insert data in your articles as you mention.
- You also can do this by [**Selecting data using JDatabase**](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)
  In this way, you can show you data in any part of your site, for example you can add the code in **index.php** file in your template, or in some override or in your custom module, etc.

Here you have more info:
[Accessing the database using JDatabase](https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)

Comment: I didn't know it. I thought he had to create a module. Thank you. I have a module ready for him just in case as he doesn't know PHP.

Comment: @Thiago it's a great choice too.